# OpenLayers.Bounds transform not working as expected

Tags: openlayers-2

I have problem with transforming bounds. It is not working for the first time, later it works just fine. At first i thought that something was still loading butsearching in firebug shows that nothing gets loaded and i think everything is provided for it to work:

Here is the code:

```
        Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2180"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs";

        var proj2180 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2180");
        var proj4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

        var bounds = OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(record.get("llbbox"));
        bounds.transform(proj4326, proj2180);
        console.log(bounds);
```

This code is placed in function. When i run it for the first time i get following console output:
13.897781645001,48.960416159343,24.621296204369,54.83756633314

when second time i get:
143457.09623933677,137520.1675486639,876176.7241084952,786832.4073041743

Answer (score 3):

try to use:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2180"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 
                             +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs";

var proj2180 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2180");
var proj4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

var bounds = map.getExtent();
bounds.transform(proj4326, proj2180);
console.log(bounds);
```

and

`map.getExtent().toGeometry().toString() returns` you to Polygon...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it wont work. I am transforming bounds to put it into maxExtent of a map, so i dont have map object yet. I want the WMS request to be sent with BBOX of transformed coordinates, the llbbox returns them in 4326. The map is created after pressing a button. When i press it for the first time maxExtent is with the coords in latlon but when i press it second time it works.

Comment: Strange but i managed to fix it. Just declared proj2180 and proj4326 earlier in my app and it started working. Maybe its take some time to initialize these variables and if they are not initialized, transform will just do nothing.

Comment: it is good to hear that your code is working :)